# How to implement EditText with MM format for month

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` component that I use to get month Input.

What I want is that if the user enters "**1**" the `EditText` should automatically show "**01**". And then if the user enters **2**, the `EditText` shows "**02**".

In fact, I want my `EditText` to always show two digits. How do I format it to show `MM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `onFocusChangeListener` to the `EditText`

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            EditText edt = (EditText) view;  
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(edt.getText()) && edt.getText().toString().trim().length < 2) {
              edt.setText("0" + edt.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        } 
    }
});
```

Also, add following in `EditText` xml tag

```
android:maxLength="2"
```